# Change UIAlertView to UIAlertController of app to get updated to iOS 8

Tags: ios7, ios8, uialertview, deprecated, uialertcontroller

I have to update to `iOS 8` some apps developed for `iOS 7`. After `UIAlertView` got `deprecated` on `iOS 8`. My question is:

Is it neccesary to check the `iOS version`, and show a `UIAlertController` rather than a `UIAlertView`?

Or can I leave the implementation of `UIAlertView`? Will `iOS` can use it for some years more? Since its `deprecated`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is "necessary", but for best compatibility going both backwards into the past and forwards into the future it is obviously best to adopt the new technology in iOS 8 and abandon the deprecated technology. So if you want your app to work both in iOS 7 and iOS 8, the broadest possible coverage would require that, yes, you use UIAlertView in iOS 7 and UIAlertController in iOS 8.

Comment: However, no one can tell you how to proceed; it's a matter of personal taste and external requirements. Personally, I always abandon backwards compatibility. So when I update my apps for iOS 8, the new versions don't run on iOS 7 and I don't care. Thus I am free to abandon all deprecated technology.

Comment: Thanks matt! It's more like I would like know the functionality of deprecated objects, to know if its common to keep them for some people. I wasn't really sure how to proceed, but the safest way is to show an UIAlertController for iOS 8, since the apps I have to update need to run in both platforms.